# After server migration only the homepage works

Tags: permalinks, database, 404-error, migration

I have recently changed hosting of my WordPress site to [VPS.net](http://vps.net/). I have moved all of my files and imported the database. Everything appeared to be fine until I clicked a link and noticed that all of my pages are bringing back a 404 except the homepage.

Site URL is http://inksquared.com

Comment: I had this problem today!
[Migrated WordPress Site – Homepage Works, All Other Pages/Links Fail](http://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0001126)

Comment: I had same issue and then it is fixed by changing .htaccess file according to default values from here https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I guess you get http://yoursite but not http://yoursite/anything

I had a similar problem and it worked when I changed

the `httpd.conf` from

```
AllowOverride None
```

to

```
AllowOverride All
```

It makes the `.htaccess` take effect.

Comment: This one worked for me. Most of the people forget about this.

Comment: This worked for me too, only had to change it in the section of `apache2.conf` for the location of my server files, `/var/www` in my case

Comment: This was part of the answer for me. I added ```AllowOverride All``` to the site configuration, but I also added ```Options FollowSymLinks```. I was then able to use custom permalinks, which also created an appropriate root .htaccess file. After that everything worked.

Comment: And don't forget to restart apache! "sudo service apache2 restart"

Comment: It worked. Make sure you change the AllowOverride option at locations in the conf file.

Comment: enabling in httpd.conf LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so did the trick in mac. remove the # to enable it

Answer (score 54):

Try flushing your mod_rewrite rules:

Dashboard -> Settings -> Permalinks

Save settings (no need to make any changes)

Comment: No need to even save, actually. The rules are flushed just by visiting that page, and part of flushing the rules involves writing to .htaccess.

Comment: I learn something new every day... :)

Comment: @john are you sure that just page loads write to .htaccess if it needs to? I was under the impression that only rewrite_rules in the database are flushed.

Comment: wp-admin/options-permalinks.php calls `flush_rewrite_rules()`, a wrapper for `WP_Rewrite::flush_rules()`, which, if `$hard` is `true` (which it is when called on that page) and the function `save_mod_rewrite_rules` exists (defined in `wp-admin/includes/misc.php`, included in all admin pages), it calls `save_mod_rewrite_rules()`. See that function's definition here: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-admin/includes/misc.php#L114

Comment: The function that actually writes the rewrite rules to .htaccess is called `insert_with_markers` (used in `save_mod_rewrite_rules()` above), defined here: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-admin/includes/misc.php#L53

Comment: This fixed it for me.

Comment: No need to open the cPanel. I was trying the accepted answer first and mine is shared hosting so couldn't find httpd.conf and live chat is still loading. And then I found this answer which does is the most easy to use solution. :D

Comment: this solved my issue (the same as  the op)

Answer (score 31):

I had faced the same problem.

I did the following to resolve it on an Ubuntu Server:

1. In */etc/apache2/apache2.conf*, edit *AllowOverride None* for **/var/www/** to *AllowOverride All*
2. Type in the following command to enable mod_rewrite for .htaccess

**sudo a2enmod rewrite**

3. Restart your apache server:

**sudo service apache2 restart**

The problem solved!!!

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't get this fixed with any of the other suggestions, but `a2enmod rewrite` did the trick.

Comment: +1 For mentioning the rewrite mod. Didn't realize that this wasn't enabled by default.

Comment: Definitely needed that `sudo a2enmod rewrite` to get this wokring, thanks!

Comment: Thanks! The command `a2enmod rewrite`did the trick for me.

Comment: Thanks Avinash!
Same with Lucas, the a2enmod rewrite did the trick for me

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 14.04 - the **000-default.conf** file can be found here `/etc/apache2/sites-available`

Or if you run multiple wp the virtual host setting would be your config file name. *e.g. **domain.conf***

You have to replace `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`

Hope this will work.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is most likely that the `.htaccess` file wasn't copied over. On Mac OS X, and in some FTP applications, this file is considered "hidden" because it starts with a `.`. If you go to the Settings -> Permalinks section in your admin section, you can regenerate this file, but it's probably best to find the version you had previously and use that again (especially if you use a caching plugin).

Answer (score 0):

Do you get a web server 404 or a WordPress 404? If it's a web server 404, you most likely didn't copy the root htaccess file over from the old installation, or it doesn't have correct permissions to run.

My first troubleshooting item would be to check and see if an htaccess file exists in the root. And if so, what it contains.

Comment: Checked the .htaccess file. It contains the same code that appeared in the permalink section of the wordpress admin panel. I changed the permissions to writable and can see no apparent changes.

Comment: @mikeyrocks Hmm... another possibility is that your new server doesn't have mod_rewrite turned on. Important: are you getting a server 404 (plain white page that says "not found"), or a WordPress 404 (styled like the rest of your site)?