# After migration works only first page

Tags: permalinks, migration, https

I migrated from a web hosting to a server in my NAT.
I did vhost with apache2 so the http server can be serve both an instance of nextcloud and a wordpress one for my home.

I had a Let's encrypt certificate for the nextcloud, I renewed it with the new address and it was all ok.

Then I did the (I thought) easy part: wordpress.

Copied the bkp files, installed mariadb + create_db + create_user + PHP + give_user_permission, populate the db with sql bkp.

I Created a certificate with let's encrypt for the www.

After this step apache is automatically instructed (by let's encrypt's certbot) that any request to http://www.mydomain has to be solved as https://www.mydomain .

Finally I checked with the browser and the first page works but all the othewrs give the error of page not found.

My problem looks similar to this [After server migration only the homepage works](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14685/after-server-migration-only-the-homepage-works), but is not the same because the solution does not work for me, so I suspect that permalinks are in http... somewhere but are wanted as https in the browsed pages.

Yesterday I was able to enter in the admin panel and I saw that it says that the prefix was https . (by the way, today is no longer working.)

The site is https://www.munerotto.it/

Comment: Yesterday I upgraded wordpress from, the admin panel and then I rebooted. I can't login anymore. I changed all the occurrences in the sqldump from "htto://www.mydomain" to "https://www.mydomain", but anything changed

Comment: I partially solved. 1) to login I point the browser to wp-login.php. 2) The article-pages slugs was not working, I moved to another option to regenerate it (/?p=XXX) and then to the one I preferred (/article-title) but it was still not working. I decided to use the default ugly slugs (/?p=XXX) and, using this workaround, it is working.